# Generate .pfx from .crt powershell (From CSR creation to .pfx)

Tags: powershell, iis, certificate, csr, godaddy-api

A little bit of context:

I used to generate CSRs from IIS "Create certificate request", import that in my provider (GoDaddy) and get a .crt in return. Then I used to go again to IIS to "Complete certificate request" and generate the .pfx

I want to automate this process as much as possible including importing the CSR to GoDaddy and downloading the .crt file.

Right now I was able to automate the CSR creation with certreq.exe but note sure how to complete the request using powershell to create the .pfx when I have the .crt file from GoDaddy. I know I can do it with openssl but I'm missing the private key.

I think when I create the CSR request with certreq.exe, it generates the .pfx on "MMC > Certificate Enrollment Requests" which has the private key so I was wondering if every time I request the CSR, I have to export that .pfx and with openssl extract the private key to use it with my.crt file from GoDaddy?

Hopefully I was able to explain correctly what I'm trying to accomplish and somebody can help me with this.

Comment: You can use the command line tool `certreq`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certreq_1 Examples can be found everywhere, like https://github.com/chrisdee/Scripts/blob/master/PowerShell/Working/certificates/GenerateCertificateSigningRequest(CSR).ps1

Comment: If you're using certreq to create the request, then use `certreq -accept` to do the matching

Comment: You can then use `certutil.exe -f -p $password -exportpfx request $certThumb $pfxFilePath` after you've accepted the signed cert response from your CA.